# Running c++ on spark

Tags: c++, apache-spark

I intend to run a c++ program on spark using rdd.pipe() operator in order to  see the possible benefits of the program running in parallel.

In terminal i run it like this:

```
./program program_mode -t input -i output
```

In spark driver i've attempted:

```
mapDataset.pipe(s"/path/to/program program_mode -t $mapDataset -i /path/to/output"
```

where mapDataset is the input rdd (type .fasta file) that i have successfully loaded in spark driver,but this doesnt work.
The general problem is that the program expects to have its input through the flags but in spark the input is in the rdd that i've created on which pipe is called.

Any idea on how i can implement this communication correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your program uses streams, then change the way it behaves.

Instead of opening an `ifstream` for a file when it's on the command line, pass in `stdin` to your functions. Same for the output stream.